# Can I put a wall and roof on an overhanging deck?

Tags: deck, porch

Is it safe to build a free-standing deck with overhangs on all four sides and then turn it into a screened porch by putting walls up on the very edge of the deck?

I don't know if it's a good idea to put the porch wall framing along the edge of the deck, on top of the rim joists, because this is on an overhang. I don't think the walls and roof will be very heavy, but I also don't know what magic number "too heavy" is.

I want to use 2x4 framing for the walls with a stud every 3 feet, assemble the walls on the deck, stand them up, screw them down through the bottom plate, and then staple a screen over them from the outside. For the roof, I was thinking of a shed style matching the house roof pitch, with exposed rafters and some thin metal roofing that we have piled up in the yard. It doesn't snow much in Georgia so there won't be much snow weight. Is this too heavy to bear on the deck overhang? Is it too lightweight to support the roof/walls appropriately?
[image: picture of design]

Comment: TLDR, the structure needs to be 24” OC max if part of the residence it will be 16” and code will probably require 2x6 studs.

Comment: I'd like to help but too much text for me. Can you pull out your question and put the background/related information in a separate section?

Comment: Sure. The gist of the question is: Is it safe to build a free-standing deck with 25% overhangs on all four sides and then turn it into a screened porch by putting walls up on the very edge of the deck?

Comment: A picture of a quick, not-to-scale pencil sketch with proposed dimensions will help ensure everyone is envisioning the same thing you're envisioning. [Edit] your post to include it (the little mountain icon above the editor box - [diy.se] will host the image for you, no need to first upload it elsewhere).

Comment: If you have not build it yet the why not put  supports under where the walls will be instead of having them on a cantilevered overhang ?

Comment: Alaska Man, the supports can't go under where the walls will be due to requirements that I explained earlier. People said the post was too long so I deleted those details. The deck will be freestanding and close to a house. The owner is unwilling to dig into the siding and especially the roof, and the porch will be accessed from outdoors only. Given the proximity to the house, the footings would have to be under the posts shadows if the posts go directly under the wall. That's why I would like to use an overhang. Also, the location is along an inside corner so two edges must be overhung.

Comment: When you say the deck is "free standing" does that mean butted up to, but not attached to the house, or does that mean out in the yard, feet or more from the main building?

Answer (score 0):

We design from the top down and build from the bottom up.

There are several issues: 1) metal roofing, 2) roof structure, 3) wall structure, 4) floor structure, 5) secure structure to existing house, 6) foundation, 7) zoning,

1) You mention using some existing metal pieces of roofing. If it’s allowed by your home owners association AND by building code, you’ll need to install it on insulation or you’ll have condensation dripping from it. (Also, you’ll need to insure the metal roofing creates a diaphragm or you’ll need to add cross strapping.)

Your code requires 20 lbs. per square foot (psf) Live Load plus a Dead Load of 1 psf for the metal roofing plus 0.5 psf for insulation plus about 1.0 psf for roof joists plus about 3.5 psf for miscellaneous items like lights, etc. for a Total Load of 20 psf + 6 psf = 26 psf.

2) The roof structure will span 10’ and may require spaces stripping on top to support the metal roofing (depending on the type). Therefore, your roof structure needs to be 2x6’s at 24” on center, depending on the species and grade of lumber. I’d use Simpson H-1 clips between each joist and the top plate to keep the roof from flying away.

3) The wall can be constructed out of 2x4’s, but will need some diagonal bracing to keep it rigid. I’d recommend 2x4 studs at 24” oc, rather than the 36” you propose. Make sure you have a double top plate that laps 4’ at splices and you have a horizontal member at 42” from the floor so you don’t fall through the screen and off the deck. Use Simpson straps from the top plates to the studs and from the studs to the floor joists. That system will weigh about  4 psf. If it’s about 8’ high, then the Total wall weight is about 32 lbs. per linear foot (plf) on the cantilevered floor joists.

4) The floor supports have a Live Load of 40 psf plus the Dead Load of about 10 psf Dead Load. In addition, the joists have the roof load and wall load on the cantilevered ends. The total roof load is 26 psf x 5’ (half the roof span) = 130 plf plus the wall load of 32 plf for a total load of 162 plf on the cantilevered joists.

After a few calculations, the total Section Modulus required is about 6.0 and your 2x8’s that you want to use is about 15.0 each or 11.2 at 16” on center. Therefore, your 2x8’s at 16” on center are adequate.

5) The Code now requires all decks, porches, etc. to be strapped to the main building for seismic resistance. Use a Simpson tie like this:

https://www.fastenersplus.com/Simpson-DTT2Z-Deck-Tension-Tie-Zmax-Finish?gclid=Cj0KCQjw7YblBRDFARIsAKkK-dJZrRsiFDrb6UevCNA1fWsgoBllbcaFbSIxYM08Q-lVaduQDD0EbOYaAvekEALw_wcB

6) Your foundation will have about 7,000 resting on it. This is not your question, but I’d make sure the two interior footings are at least 18” square. (The end footings can be smaller...they carry half the load the interior footings carry.)

7) Before you start, you should check with your planning department to make sure it’s allowed. (Verify setbacks, height restrictions, maximum lot coverage, etc.)

Summary:
Yep, you can use 2x8 floor joists at 16” on center.

Comment: Fantastic engineering assessment as usual. OP says "free standing" deck and "screened room". Point #1) If it's a screened room, there won't be much condensation dripping from the metal roofing (other than morning dew) will there? The inside vs outside temps won't be impacted by the insulation value of window screen. Point #5) If this is truly free-standing (I take that to mean not butted up against the house) there wouldn't be any need to attach it to the main residence in any way, would there? Clarification on just how "free standing" from the OP would be good.

Comment: @FreeMan For 1) I’d be careful about condensation. My experience is that the interior is cooler than the exterior when the sun comes out. That’s a recipe for condensation. The insulation is to isolate the metal from the interior environment. For 5) you are correct if it’s truly free standing (i.e.: not touching anywhere.) The OP said, “and then turn it into a screened porch”. I mis-read that as turning it into part of the house.

Comment: Fair enough on 1)... you seem to have _far_ more experience than I. I was just thinking that the inside temp of a metal roof would be pretty similar to the outside. Granted the air inside _should_ be cooler due to the shade. It's in GA, so we know the humidity should be pretty high! ;)